# Django-Allauth social login not available (socialaccount.providers not passed to templates)

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, django-allauth

I'm on django 1.8 and lastest django-allauth. I have followed the official docs to install. However after creating a facebook social app, i don't see it in the login page. Anyway here is what i've done:

```
# Settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # Required by `allauth` template tags
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    # `allauth` specific context processors
    'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook':
        {'SCOPE': ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_friends'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'METHOD': 'js_sdk',  # instead of 'oauth2'
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False,}
}

SITE_ID = 1
```

Created a Site with domain and name as `example.com:8000`
Created a facebook app with provider `Facebook`, and corresponding `Client id` and `Secret key` also added previously created site to 'sites'
In facebook for developers set domain to the same domain in site (`example.com:8000`).

**Problem screenshot :**

[image]

**Templates code :**

[Login template source code](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/templates/account/login.html) and 
[Provider list snippet source code](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/templates/socialaccount/snippets/provider_list.html)

**Edit :**

I suspect the problem is django 1.8 specific as TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS is deprecated since django 1.8, and allauth expects TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in settings file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Django 1.8 the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting is handled this way:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            # needed for admin templates
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            # allauth needs this from django
            'django.core.context_processors.request',
            # allauth specific context processors
            'sites.allauth.account.context_processors.account',
            'sites.allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount',
          ],
       },
    }
]
```

If that was the only problem you were experiencing then this change should fix things.